# Send Information from BrightScript to Node.js using a BrightSign device

Tags: javascript, node.js, brightscript

I have enable Node.js to my device (BrightSign) and now I can use JavaScript objects for BrightScript, for example `BSDeviceInfo` for getting information of my device, so far everything is OK.

Now reading the [PDF documentation](http://brightsignbiz.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/JavaScript%20Objects%20for%20BrightScript%20%286.1%29.pdf): (*Using JavaScript Objects for BrightScript*) I assume these JavaScript objects are limited and I can not get all the information that BrightScript can give me.

So, the question is: does any one know how can I send information from BrightScript to Node.js (or JavaScript Objects for BrightScript) and maybe vice versa?

Comment: Take a look here and edit your question. You should have some code of what you tried, what you expected, and what happened instead. Often, doing this correctly answers questions for people. When it doesn't it allows us to help you without doing the work for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Start here and see how close it gets you -> https://brightsign.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115004005933-Enable-NodeJs-on-my-BrightSign-player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UDP (`roDatagramEvent`) in your **autorun.brs** file to communicate between them.

You can find an example in this repo https://github.com/alexnathanson/BrightsignAPI